# How to integrate a Scrapy Web Crawler with a Luigi Data Pipeline?

Tags: python, http, web-crawler, data-processing, luigi

(Long time user && First question && Nervous to ask) is True

I'm currently building a Python backend that will be deployed to a single AWS EC2 instance which has the following architecture:

---

|---- *Data Sources* -----| *Temp Storage* | - *Data Processing* --- | -----   *DB* ---- |

**Web Crawler Data**----*Save to S3* =\
**API Data**-----------------*Save to S3* ==> **Lugi Data Pipeline** --> MongoDB

---

As shown above, we have different ways of fetching data (ie API Requests, Scrapy Web Crawler, etc...) but the tricky/difficult part is coming up with a simple and fault-tolerant way to connect the received data with the Luigi Data Pipeline.

Is there a way to integrate a web crawler's output into a Luigi Data Pipeline? If not, how is the best way to go about bridging the gap between the HTTP data fetchers and the Luigi tasks?

Any advice, documents, or articles would be super appreciated! Also, if you need more details I'll get them in here as quick as possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never used luigi.  But I do use scrapy. I am going to guess the real question is how you notify luigi in a reasonable way that there is new data to be processed?

There is a similar question you could learn from here:[When a new file arrives in S3, trigger luigi task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43617386/when-a-new-file-arrives-in-s3-trigger-luigi-task)
Perhaps you guys work at the same place:).

I would strongly suggest hosting your spider in scrapyd and using scrapyd-client to drive it.  There are ALL KINDS of hairy things that pop up if you try to run scrapy in other tools that use the twisted library (not sure if luigi does).  I would drive the spider using scrapyd-client and let your spider post to a trigger url that tells luigi to kick off the task somehow.

Again, as I haven't used luigi, I don't know details there...but you do not want to be busy-checking/polling to find out if the job is done.

I have a django web app and I kick off the spider, store the jobid from scrapyd-client, and get a json tap on the shoulder when it's done, then I use celery and solr to ingest the data.

Edit to include pipeline code from comments below:

```
        for fentry in item['files']:

            # open and read the file
            pdf = open(rootdir+os.path.sep+fentry['path'],'rb').read()

            # just in case we need cookies
            cj     = CookieJar()
            opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

            # set the content type
            headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }

            #fill out the object
            json_body = json.dumps({
            'uid'   : 'indeed-'+item['indeed_uid'],
            'url'   : item['candidate_url'],
            'first_name' : fname,
            'last_name'  : lname,
            'pdf'     : base64.b64encode(pdf).decode(),
            'jobid': spider.jobid
            }).encode()
            #, ensure_ascii=False)

            # send the POST and read the result
            request = urllib.request.Request('http://localhost:8080/api/someapi/', json_body, headers)
            request.get_method = lambda: 'POST'
            response = opener.open(request)
```

Comment: Great point, I definitely want to stay away from polling at all costs. One last question, can you elaborate a bit more on that JSON tap? Does that occur when the entire crawler process has completed or after a single page has been fetched and needs processing? Still contemplating whether to start the processing after an individual page has been fetched or whether to aggregate all data into a single file and wait till after? However, my gut feeling says the latter is a more error prone solution/can lead to corrupted files.

Comment: I do it per item as the items are scraped (not at spider end) by leveraging the item pipelines in scrapy.  The best batching/processing style depends completely on your backend.  I've included most of my process_item() function from the relevent pipeline in my edited answer for reference.  If you don't want to do it per item...you can export to json or csv almost natively with scrapy then send a tap to the server using a CloseSpider signal or something similar.

Comment: If your item's are VERY simple then you don't have to use pipelines just use exporter (builtin pipeline like thing) https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html.  Then you can trigger on SpiderClose or something else.

Comment: If my answer was acceptable...please accept it as the official answer